# Cross origin attribute breaks video playback

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a React snippet that works for local video blobs but not for external URLs. If I take off the crossOrigin attribute the video will play for both, but I need the attribute for canvas data exporting. Any reason why cross-origin would stop playback?

```
<video
    autoPlay
    controls
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
    onPause={props.onPause}
    onPlay={props.onPlay}
    width='320'>
    <source src={props.src} />
</video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#cors-settings-attribute):

> When the user agent is required to perform a potentially CORS-enabled fetch of an absolute URL URL with a mode mode that is either "No CORS", "Anonymous", or "Use Credentials", optionally using a referrer source referrer source, with an origin origin, and with a default origin behaviour default which is either "taint" or "fail", it must run the first applicable set of steps from the following list. The default origin behaviour is only used if mode is "No CORS". This algorithm wraps the fetch algorithm above, and labels the obtained resource as either CORS-same-origin or CORS-cross-origin, or blocks the resource entirely.

You are saying "Get this content with cross-origin permissions", the server you are requesting it from is *not granting those permissions*, so the browser blocks access to it entirely.

Comment: Yeah it was a header issue with the cdn provider. Thanks.